# Vectors and Matrices assistance

Tags: matrices, vectors

I'm currently stuck with this homework question. I was able to figure out (a) but now I can't figure out (b).
Can someone maybe help out?

A man wishes to row the shortest possible distance from north to south across a river which is flowing at 3 km/hr from the east. He can row at 4 km/hr.

(a) In which direction should he steer? 
At an angle (in degrees) of 48.59025877 east of south.

(b) Suppose that when the man is in the middle of the river, a wind of 5 km/hr from the southwest starts.

In which direction should he steer to move straight across the river? 
At an angle (in degrees) of _________ west/east of south.

Which bank of the river will the rower reach first?

The north/The south/Neither bank.

Comment: How is this a **matrices** question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure:

$3$ km/hr from east to west , and $5$ km/hr from southwest to northeast. 
What will be the resultant speed and direction of opposition forces?

Once you get that vector, resolve it into 2 parts: $1$ along the direction he wants to move, and another perpendicualr to it.

He should steer only in the direction perpendicular to the direction in which he wants to go to balance the counter forces. The wind and the river will do the rest of the job

Comment: I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.
Would it be 2km/hr south to west?

Comment: @Franky Speed of what  is $2$ km/hr?